# Memcacheing WHERE IN query

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

`myModel.gql("WHERE prop IN :1", myList)`

After running this query, how can I memcache entities that match each prop separately?

For example, if myList is: `['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3']`

How do I make 3 separate memcache entries, one for each item in the list?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302525/why-does-memcached-not-support-multi-set

Answer (score 1):

```
query = MyModel.gql(<your GQL query WHERE statement>)

for mymodel in query:
    memcache.add(somekey, mymodel.somedata, 60)
```

Where 60 is the expiration time in seconds, which can be any expiration that is appropriate for your app. Also, please note the difference between "add()" and "set()" functions - add() will only add data if it's not already in memcache, set() will overwrite anything already added under that key.

Comment: But doesn't this cache each entity separately? There should only be 3 memcache entries in my given example, regardless of number of entities returned.